# android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, grid-layout

activitymain.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:background="@color/primary_text"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/adherence_text"
                            android:id="@+id/action_with_adherence"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 actionWithAdherence=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.action_with_adherence);
        //second parameter 3 represents it has 3 column
        //actionWithAdherence.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        actionWithAdherence.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));

    actionWithAdherence.setAdapter(new DashboardAdherence(this, actionListWithAdherence));
```

calling the adapter in this class.

Adapter xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adherence_section"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <at.grabner.circleprogress.CircleProgressView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cpv_maxValue="100"
        app:cpv_textSize="15dp"
        app:cpv_textColor="@color/white"
        app:cpv_unit="%"
        app:cpv_unitSize="10dp"
        app:cpv_unitColor="@color/white"
        app:cpv_unitScale="1"
        app:cpv_rimColor="@color/secondary_background"
        app:cpv_rimWidth="10dp"
            app:cpv_barWidth="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/action_adherence"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/action_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Exercise"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter onBindAdaper() :

```
  if ((position+1)%3==0){
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)adherenceHolder.adherenceSection.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 1);
            adherenceHolder.adherenceSection.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        else
        {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)adherenceHolder.adherenceSection.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 1, 1);
            adherenceHolder.adherenceSection.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
```

**Issue:**

Since in my main activity I am setting the view to the gridlayout but in the adapter using the linear layout. So Android is not able to cast the linear layout to the grid layout. THat causes the exception.

Is there any way I can able to cast the layout?

Comment: use GridLayout.LayoutParams instead of LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: I changed but got another error now "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout$LayoutParams"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Grid Layout manager params

```
GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams
                = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) adherenceHolder.adherenceSection.getLayoutParams();
```